# Can we use HTML instead of XAML for Visual Studio WPF applications

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I m trying to learn working and functions of Visual Studio by myself using you tube videos and so.

So I came across this option called WPF applications in new project, I came to know that we use that to make some good UI exe for windows. 
SO when I open a new project on that, it has c# coding backend and design tab along with XAML coding platform

And I came to know that XAML is used to design the front end, just like we use HTML,CSS for web apps.

I m good with HTML, CSS, JS. So I wonder whether there is an option for switching the XAML with HTML in Visual Studio?

Comment: YES, it's called ASP.NET, and you develop for browsers instead

Answer (score 0):

There is no option to convert HTML to XAML and vice-versa . you should understand WPF is different development from WEB

Comment: so, XAML is the only language to work with wpf applications?